# Does the Firestore JavaScript library use local cache by default?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have noticed that the metadata from snapshots indicate the they are sometimes coming from cache even though I have not enabled persistence.

`payload.doc.metadata.fromCache` returns `true` often even though I have not enabled persistence i.e. `enablePersistence()`.

Is there some decent documentation on the mechanics of Firestore's local caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Firestore has an in-memory snapshot of all data you're already listening to. If you attach another observer to that same data, it'll return the data from the in-memory cache, instead of re-reading it from the server.

Comment: That is pretty impressive.